# Facebook comment mirroring option not available in devtools

Tags: facebook, comments, mirroring

I'm trying to get comment mirroring on one of my website, I already do this for an other website, but I can't get this to work with an other one, option it's simply not available.
Moderation and comment are OK, but I don't have the option to choose a Page to mirror comment with.

Here (option not available) :

[image: What i'm getting]

Here an other website with the option :

[image: What I'm suppose to have)]

What i'm suppose to do ? Facebook documentation do not tell anything about this.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like they are going to remove this soon anyway, _“With the release of the Facebook SDK version 4.28.0, Comment Mirroring is deprecated. It will be supported until February 5, 2018.”_ (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments)

Comment: Deprecated information is not display in French documentation...